# Why do negative integers not equal their corresponding positive integers?

Tags: arithmetic, square-numbers

According to my logic, $1=(-1)$, $2=(-2)$, $3=(-3)$, etc.
This can't be right but please tell me where I went wrong.

$$\begin{array}{l}
{\rm{Suppose}}\\
x = \left( { - x} \right)\\
{x^2} = {\left( { - x} \right)^2}\\
{x^2} = {x^2}\\
\sqrt {{x^2}}  = \sqrt {{x^2}} \\
x = x
\end{array}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% faaagCart1ev2aaaKnaaaaWenf2ys9wBH5garuavP1wzZbqedmvETj
% 2BSbqefm0B1jxALjharqqtubsr4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0x
% bbL8FesqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaq
% pepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-xfr-xb9Gqpi0dc9adbaqaaeGaciGa
% aiaabeqaamaabaabaaGceaqabeaacaqGtbGaaeyDaiaabchacaqGWb
% Gaae4BaiaabohacaqGLbaabaGaamiEaiabg2da9maabmaabaGaeyOe
% I0IaamiEaaGaayjkaiaawMcaaaqaaiaabofacaqGXbGaaeyDaiaabg
% gacaqGYbGaaeyzaiaabccacaqGIbGaae4BaiaabshacaqGObGaaeii
% aiaabohacaqGPbGaaeizaiaabwgacaqGZbaabaGaamiEamaaCaaale
% qabaGaaGOmaaaakiabg2da9maabmaabaGaeyOeI0IaamiEaaGaayjk
% aiaawMcaamaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaaaOqaaiaadIhadaahaaWcbe
% qaaiaaikdaaaGccqGH9aqpcaWG4bWaaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaaGc
% baWaaOaaaeaacaWG4bWaaWbaaSqabeaacaaIYaaaaaqabaGccqGH9a
% qpdaGcaaqaaiaadIhadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaaabeaaaOqaaiaa
% dIhacqGH9aqpcaWG4baaaaa!5D90!
$$

Comment: If you owe the bank a hundred bucks, is that the same thing as having a hundred bucks in savings?

Comment: You should write this flow in the exact opposite direction to what you wrote (i.e., start with $x=x$, not with $x=-x$).

Comment: I see what you mean and I know this logic must be wrong but where?

Comment: Okay now I understand.

Comment: I find this question comical and thus worthy of being posted; essentially I started from an equation that isn't true to begin with and thus anything I derive with it is not true as well.

Comment: $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x\mapsto x^2$ is not injective, i.e. you can't "cancel" $^2$.

Comment: @egreg As Aristotle argued, the ugly is a species of the ridiculous.  I was working in special relativity and I have a negative sign that is giving me grief and I resorted to this idea to get rid of it.  Obviously I received an answer to my problem.

Comment: `x = x` is an axiom, not something you need to prove. So the entire "proof" reduces to: $x = (-x) \Rightarrow x = x$. Which is in fact true, because a false premise implies *anything*, but it doesn't match the title of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You start with assuming that $ x = (-x)$. That possible,  but if we solve this we get $$x = -x$$ $$x + x = 0$$ $$2x = 0 $$ $$ x = 0 $$
So $x = 0$. Now you can see why the rest holds.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete your third equation and adjust the following equations accordingly, you go from $x^2 = (-x)^2$ to $\sqrt{x^2} = \sqrt{(-x)^2}$. This makes it more obvious that you have been led astray by a false equivalence. Kind of like what is going on with the Trump and Clinton Foundations.